# Error for deploy and virtual host Laravel project with Docker and Apache

Tags: laravel, docker, apache, docker-compose, deployment

I am trying to deploy Laravel with Docker using only packages like Apache, I also want to set up a virtual host to run my Laravel project, these are the files I have so far:

##### `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8080:80" # Cambia el puerto a 80 para Apache
    expose:
      - "80"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bdevents
      MYSQL_USER: j
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ****
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ****
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  db_data:
```

##### `Dockerfile`

```
# Usa una imagen que ya tenga Apache y PHP
FROM php:8.2-apache

# Instalar extensiones y bibliotecas necesarias
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    nodejs npm \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Instalar extensiones PHP necesarias
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath gd zip pdo_mysql

# Habilitar el módulo de Apache para rewrite (si es necesario)
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Copiar los archivos de la aplicación
COPY . /var/www/html

# Establecer el directorio de trabajo
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Configurar el host virtual de Apache
COPY apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY apache2.conf /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

# Habilitar el host virtual y recargar la configuración de Apache
RUN a2ensite 000-default.conf
RUN service apache2 restart
```

##### `apache-config.conf`

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName events.laravel
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I run the command `docker compose up -d --build`, I have these issues:

```
 => CACHED [app  9/10] RUN a2ensite 000-default.conf                                                                                                               0.0s
 => ERROR [app 10/10] RUN service apache2 restart                                                                                                                  3.3s 
------
 > [app 10/10] RUN service apache2 restart:
2.913 Restarting Apache httpd web server: apache2 failed!
3.029 The apache2 configtest failed. ... (warning).
3.029 Output of config test was:
3.079 AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.
3.079 Action 'configtest' failed.
3.079 The Apache error log may have more information.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c service apache2 restart" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

What is the problem? Why doesn't it do the deployment for me and why doesn't it create the virutalhost correctly? Im new in this technollogy, its my first time.

Answer (score 0):

Docker is very particular about installing any type of package, it looks like Apache was not installed correctly. Try installing Apache again.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).